# Django - getting Error "Reverse for 'detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:" when using {% url "music:fav" %}

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am learning django framework from last 4 days.
Today I was trying to retrieve a URL in HTML template by using

> {% url "music:fav" %}

where I set the namespace in music/urls.py as

> app_name= "music"

and also I have a function named fav().
Here is the codes:

music/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("<album_id>/", views.detail, name="detail"),
path("<album_id>/fav/", views.fav, name="fav"),
]
```

music/views.py

```
def fav(request):
    song = Song.objects.get(id=1)
    song.is_favorite = True
    return render(request, "detail.html")
```

in detail.html I used

```
{% url 'music:fav' %}
```

But I dont know why this is showing this error:

> NoReverseMatch at /music/1/ Reverse for 'detail' with no arguments not
>   found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['music\/(?P[^/]+)\/$']

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
path("<album_id>/fav/", views.fav, name="fav"),
```

This URL needs the **album_id**. Something like this:

```
{% url 'music:fav' 1 %}
{% url 'music:fav' album.id %}
```

Comment: Hi I met the same issue,but when I use 1 it works,when I use album.id it says 'Reverse for 'update_comment' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['comment\\-(?P<news_pk>[0-9]+)$']'.So it seems I didn't past the id to the template.Could you help me check it ?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014809/reverse-for-update-comment-with-arguments-not-found-1-patterns-trie?noredirect=1#comment87046628_50014809

Comment: When you use 1 it works only on the surface. In reality you will be moved always to the place with value 1. Check what is your object name. To be precise you have to figure out what is your 'album' in your case.

Answer (score 5):

The reason is because your view needs an `album_id` argument

music/views.py

```
def fav(request, album_id):
    # then filter by album id instead of a default value of 1
    song = Song.objects.get(id=album_id)
    song.is_favorite = True
    return render(request, "detail.html")
```

the trick here is that your url expects to match

**views.py**

> def fav(request, `album_id`):

**urls**

> path("`<int:album_id>`/fav/", views.fav, name="fav"),