# Rendering error: Reverse for 'ph' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<answer>[^/]+)/ph\\-data/$']

Tags: django, url-parameters

I'm new to coding and here I'm trying to build website that simply take in what the user wants to see from selected range, as I run the server I'm face with this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Django Version: 2.1.3
Python Version: 3.7.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'zigview']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\user\Desktop\Frouniter\FrounterWeb- postgreDB\zigview\templates\FrounterWeb\index.html, error at line 12
   Reverse for 'ph' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<answer>[^/]+)/ph\\-data/$']
   2 : <html lang="en">
   3 : <head>
   4 :      {%load staticfiles%}
   5 :      <!-- Mobile resizing  and bootstrap -->
   6 :      {%include 'FrounterWeb/Lib-includes/Mobile-Response.html'%}
   7 : 
   8 :              <!-- Javascript action-->
   9 :      {%include 'FrounterWeb/Lib-includes/JavaScript-action.html'%}
   10 : 
   11 :                 <!-- Libary of chart and gage  -->
   12 :         {%include 'FrounterWeb/Lib-includes/Gr aphs-files.ht ml'%}
   13 : 
   14 :         <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'FrounterWeb/img/Logo.png' %}">
   15 :         <title>Frounter-Agrotech monitoring</title>
   16 : 
   17 : 
   18 : 
   19 : 
   20 :     </head>
   21 : 
   22 : <body class="body" style="background-color:#f6f6f6">


Traceback:

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  154.                 response = response.render()

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  309.                 return nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  442.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  622.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /
Exception Value: Reverse for 'ph' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<answer>[^/]+)/ph\\-data/$']
```

I'm sorry I had ask something so simply

What I had try:

1. try swtich to pk:   to
2. try add into slug  or

I readed this url link: [Django - getting Error "Reverse for 'detail' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:" when using {% url "music:fav" %}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944443/django-getting-error-reverse-for-detail-with-no-arguments-not-found-1-patt)

My Codes:

My Views code:

```
    try:
     class index(ListView):
     model = tank_system
     template_name = 'FrounterWeb/extends/includes.html'
     ordering = ['-datetime']

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        return{'tank':self.get_queryset()}
    #def get_queryset(self):
     #   return

     except:
   logger.error('index page request failed/errors')


 try:
class ph(ListView):
    model = tank_system
    template_name = 'FrounterWeb/extends/ph.html'
    context_object_name = tank_system
    ordering = ['-datetime'] # sort dates in descending order

    def post(self, request, answer):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = YourForm(request.POST)

            if form.is_valid():
                answer = form.cleaned_data['value']


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        #do a selection of which path to do 
        return{'tank': self.get_queryset()}

    except:
     logger.error('PH page Functions failed/errors')
```

Apps URl codes:

```
        from django.urls import path
        from . import views #function views
        path(r'<str:answer>/ph-data/', login_required(views.ph.as_view()), name='ph'),
```

My HTML codes for user to in put data:

```
{%block Buttonbar%}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="mx-auto">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-primary">

          <div class = "container-fluid" >
          <form action="{% url 'zigview:ph-data' answer %}" method = "post">
<select class="custom-select" id="datetimefilter" name = "dropdown">
  <option selected="selected" disabled>Select:</option>
    <option value="Today">Today</option>
  <option value="Yestday">Yestday</option>
  <option value="ThWeek">This Week</option>
  <option value="PreWeek">Previous Week</option>
  <option value="ThMonths">This Months</option>
  <option value="PerMonths">Previous Month</option>
  <option value="Thisyear">This Year</option>
  <option value="Lastyear">Last Year</option>
    </select>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="post" name="submit-select">

          <div class="container-fluid">
  <a>Select Range Dates:<input  class="form-control" type="date"/> to <input  class="form-control" type="date"/></a>
  </div>

    </form>
            </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
</div>
{%endblock Buttonbar%}
```

Summary what results:

I want be able take in variable and maybe see from console for now, this variable will be pass into python script and use it to select data, month and years to see

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue seems to be that `answer` is undefined when your template renders (I don't see it added to any context).  Once you have a value in `answer`, you should be able to do the following:

```
{% url 'zigview:ph-data' answer=answer %}
```

---

Update:  OP did not know how to add `answer` to his context dictionary, so I'll expand on that part.  To add additional values to your context dictionary, you add them to your class-based view's `get_context_data` method:

```
class ph(TemplateView):
    ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # do a selection of which path to do 
        return {
            'tank': self.get_queryset(),
            'answer': 42,
        }
        # the answer that we use above will be used as the parameter to the url in the template.
```

Comment: Did you add `answer` to the context dictionary in `ph.get_context_data` ?

Comment: I don't think so, how do I add, sorry :(